# What is a effect of using green tea with workout?

Tags: workout, health, heart-rate

I am using green tea while workout. I want to know how does it effect for body and health? As I know drink green tea loose weight.Does it makes heart rate high?

Comment: You need to drink a lot of tea to start loosing weight ( 12 cups a day I believe) . Tea contain  caffeine so yes it can increase the hearth rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green tea doesn't have a lot of caffeine (compared to say coffee or black tea) but I suppose if you're drinking a lot you could get your heart rate up. There are definitely positive effects on health:

> Long-term consumption of tea catechins could be beneficial against high-fat diet-induced obesity and type II diabetes and could reduce the risk of coronary disease. Further research that conforms to international standards should be performed to monitor the pharmacological and clinical effects of green tea and to elucidate its mechanisms of action.

[Link to study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2855614/)